# PG::ConnectionBad Error when trying to run rake db:migrate after creating model, using postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, error-handling, rake

Trying to get my rails up and running but am having a problem. When creating my new rails app on the command line I ran the usual

```
rails new PhotoApp -d postgresql
```

Generated my core scaffold.  Then generated a model with attributes in the terminal and that was fine.  After creating my model I first ran `rake db:create` and that returned a long log of characters with at the top telling me `FATAL: role "PhotoApp" does not exist` so then I tried `rake db:migrate` and that didn't work either returning me

```
rake aborted!
PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL:  role "PhotoApp" does not exist
/Users/@#$%^$#/Code/Projects/PhotoApp/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

WTF is going on here?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that Postgres isn't finding your app.  What does your `database.yml` file look like?

I would first run the rake task again, using the `--trace` as suggested:

```
    rake db:create --trace
```

That will give you a more verbose tracing, so you can try to isolate the problem.
From experience I can tell you though that 'Roles' in Postgres can be a nightmare.  How did you install Postgres on your machine?  HomeBrew?  The Postgres App?

Please post the full trace, as well as your `database.yml` file.  This will help better assess the problem!

Comment: I ran the trace and not exactly sure what it's telling me but this is what it states.  ** Invoke db:create (first_time)
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Invoke rails_env (first_time)
** Execute rails_env
** Execute db:create

Comment: I just installed the ruby gem `install gem pg` before I ran the `rails new PhotoApp -d postgresql` believing that's all I needed to do initialize on my machine.

Comment: If you haven't used Postgres before, you'll need to get it set up on your machine.  I used [this](http://marcinkubala.wordpress.com/2013/11/11/postgresql-on-os-x-mavericks/) tutorial to set up postgres on my Mac, and it went very smoothly

Comment: It was setup on my machine with Homebrew. @ajsavant17 I did it like 3 months ago when I installed ruby. I haven't ran into this problem before with my databases in the rails framework. Im trying to figure out how to reset the postgresql server, maybe that will help. Im not sure why I have a username and password field in my database.yml file either when Ive seen from other users that they with postgresql.